# WinForms TreeView - "Selected Node" indicator

Tags: .net, winforms, treeview

What is the best way to leave some indicator of which TreeNode is selected in a TreeView on a WinForm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disable the HideSelection flag on the TreeView control. By default, the selected node highlight is hidden when the control looses focus.

Comment: Why would they turn that off by default. weird.

Answer (score 0):

[Checkboxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.checkboxes.aspx), or if you want a less invasive way you might try just changing [the node's background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.backcolor.aspx).

Comment: -1 for incompleteness. Would you use the checkboxes only if the tv is not focussed? Or only if the app looses focus? How would you do it?